# What are the tools I should know to start a career in Data Science?

Tags: data

Based on what I have seen on the internet, here is a list of things I should be knowing:

1. Python
2. SQL
3. mySQL
4. MS Excel
5. Statistics
6. Machine Learning
7. Probability
8. Calculus
9. Linear Algebra
10. R
11. MongoDB
12. Java
13. Scala
14. Spark
15. Pandas
16. Hive
17. PIG
18. Big Data
19. Hadoop
20. XML
21. JSON
22. NumPy

Is this a comprehensive List? Are there more to add here?

Comment: This kind of question is not answerable: the list of trendy tools/methods changes all the time, you could add a 1000 terms to it and it would still be far from complete. Additionally I don't think there's anything somebody "should be knowing", the field is too vast and specialized.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start with Data Science, instead of looking for any such comprehensive list of tools, start with some course and simultaneously practice coding (competitive programming, maybe from [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) or [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/) etc.) and Machine Learning (maybe from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) etc.) and learn things on the go as they are required because what tools you may need would actually depend upon the actual use case.

So, coming to your question to give you a list (by cutting down your already seemingly long list) so that you can actually start:

1. Start with some relevant course like [Machine Learning by Prof. Andrew NG on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning?) (6th in your list) (In all introductory courses, Statistics (5th in your list), Probability (7th in your list), Calculus (8th in your list), Linear Algebra (9th in your list) are not much needed and you can make it without explicitly studying those subjects first, just read the relevant things when they come up in the course. This doesn't mean you shouldn't study these subjects or they are not required, but that you don't need to have had an explicit course on these topics to start with.
2. Whichever course you choose, it will have programming exercises in some particular Language (`Python` (1st in your list), `R`(10th in your list), `Java` (12th in your list), `Scala` (13th in your list)). So choose just one among these depending on the one you have in your course (The course I mentioned has programming exercises in `MATLAB` (so yeah, your `comprehensive list+=1`)). Now again you need not know the chosen language completely to start with because all the introductory courses give some introduction to the required programming language also. HackerRank has modules (under section Language Proficiency on your dashboard if you login in the website) for most of the programming languages and each module starts with the classic question of "Hello World". Open module of the chosen language and do first 15-20 questions and you will know enough of the language to start with.
3. While you are doing a course and simultaneously doing programming exercises in a chosen language, start a course on Algorithms (like one offered by [MIT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtSuA80QTyo&list=PLUl4u3cNGP61Oq3tWYp6V_F-5jb5L2iHb) that you can find on YouTube) because Algorithms is like Grammar of Coding and it will also make you much better in any language you start with.
4. Now as you do Algorithms, as soon as you finish a topic, open HackerRank or LeetCode etc. and practise questions on that topic because coding is better with Algorithms and you understand Algorithms by coding!

Now, here it's been too much "simultaneously", it's not a rule of thumb to do all of these as simultaneously as it may seem by reading this answer. Basically, start with any of these 4 "steps" and accordingly when you feel the need of others do that and so on.

That's all, leave other tools in your list to your later self when you will no longer need to read this answer and you would actually be typing an answer for a similar question asked by some new future Data Scientist looking for another comprehensive list.

THE KEY IS TO JUST START, ANYTHING!